# how to extract values from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

my grid view is this i want to when i click Approve button it insert in to my db

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="222px" Width="451px">
             <Columns>

            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" ButtonType="Button" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Rejected" ButtonType="Button" Text="Disapprove" />

   </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnRowCommand` Event handler to your grid as here:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gridview1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="222px" Width="451px">
         <Columns>

        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Rejected" ButtonType="Button" Text="Disapprove" />

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and add following codes for handling approve command button on click:

```
    protected void gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "approve")
        {
            //Code for inserting items in database goes here.
        }
    }
```